# postgresql how to join a srtring_agg?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

assume you have a simple invoice items table like:

```
Create table
( Id serial,
  serie character,
  invoice integer,
  price numeric )
```

prices are repeated within the items for the same invoice

```
1,'A',10,25.00
2,'A',10,25.00
3,'A',10,25.00
4,'A',10,15.00
5,'A',10,15.00
6,'A',10,15.00
7,'A',10,5.00
8,'A',10,5.00
9,'A',10,5.00
10,'A',10,5.00
```

I want to summarize by invoice counting items by price, something like

```
serie  invoice breakdown
'A'         10 25.00 3,15.00 3,5.00 4
```

It comes easy using a subquery but it takes forever in live data because the subquery runs isolated and repeatedly for each invoice, I have had surprising results using joins but in this case I can't make it work

```
with
v1 as (select serie, invoice, price, count(1) quant from vitems group 1,2,3 order by 1,2,3),
v2 as (select serie, invoice from v1 group by 1,2 order by 1,2),
v3 as (select v.serie, v.invoice, (select string_agg((u.price||' ') || u.quant, ',') breakdown from 
        (select w.serie, w.invoice, w.price, w.quant from v1 w where v.serie=w.serie and w.invoice=v.invoice) u) from v2 v)
select * from v3
```

v1 takes 0.6 secs, v2 0.4 secs and v3 takes 54.5 secs

any idea to eliminate v3's subquery [(select string_agg((u.price||' ') || u.quant, ',') breakdown from (select w.serie, w.invoice, w.price, w.quant from v1 w where v.serie=w.serie and w.invoice=v.invoice) u)] converting it into a left join?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may calculate the quantity in a single CTE and then apply `STRING_AGG`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31f8a/1)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH t
AS (
    SELECT serie
        ,invoice
        ,Price
        ,count(*) AS qty
    FROM vitems
    GROUP BY serie
        ,invoice
        ,Price
    )
SELECT Serie
    ,Invoice
    ,STRING_AGG(price || ' ' || qty, ',' ORDER BY Price DESC)
FROM t
GROUP BY Serie
    ,Invoice
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31f8a/1/0)**:

```
| serie | invoice |             string_agg |
|-------|---------|------------------------|
|     A |      10 | 25.00 3,15.00 3,5.00 4 |
```